# Get the list of reports based on specific object

Tags: reporting, reports-api, custom-reports

I am not able to get the list of reports based on specific object. Is there any way to get the list of Report Names and Report Ids based on specific object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way to do this. The only way I do know to do this strikes me as ridiculously complicated, actually.

The [Describe information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm) provided by the Reports and Dashboards API *mostly* has parity with the Metadata API, but what's missing is the critical piece needed for your question: the identity of the associated Report Type's primary and joined sObjects. We can't grab it out of the column info, either: the sObject-level data's not there, and fields are often represented by internal names *other* than their actual API names.

So the way to do this appears to me to be to go to the Metadata API first.

You'd need to extract the metadata for all of your [`ReportType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_reporttype.htm) entries. From that, you can get the `baseObject`, the main object of the report, and walk the recursive `join` structure to get the names (`relationship`) of the other sObjects that are joined on the report. That'd net you a list of report types and which sObjects they include.

Then you need a list of all your reports to review. Luckily, you can get that with plain old SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Report
```

All the usual limitations apply, of course - you won't get any reports you can't see, like reports in other people's private folders.

Then you need to walk through your list of reports and figure out which ones go with which Report Type - and therefore with which sObjects. You can do that in a couple of ways. You could keep using the Metadata API to pull down [Reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm) by Developer Name, or you can switch over to the [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm) to execute a Report Describe call for each of your reports by Salesforce Id. Either way, what you need is the `reportType` key in the resulting metadata.

Correlate the reports back to the report types, and you'll have enough data to say which reports include which objects. Note, though, that this only covers the primary and joined objects of the report. If an object has fields added to the report via lookup, that object will not be included in this analysis.

This sounds like quite a bit of work to me, but it is doable and it can be done in Apex provided your user has permission to talk to the Metadata API.